# Selenium + Cucumber + TestNG with multiple tabs in one Scenario Outline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tabs, cucumber, stress-testing, testng.xml

I am having a thought of giving a stress test on my webpage, which can be simplified to "a group of people clicking on the same button on the page at the same time"

Therefore, I am wondering if I can do a Scenario Outline with my selenium + cucumber + testNG test suite as follows:

- Given open tab 1 and get the button ready
- And open tab 2 and get the button ready
- And open tab 3 and get the button ready
- When open tab 4 and get the button ready
- Then click the button on tab 4
- And click the button on tab 3
- And click the button on tab 2
- And click the button on tab 1

I have only done some shallow research by far that selenium is able to manipulate different tabs with `windowHandles()`, but will it be fit for this kinda cucumber framework?

Thanks in advance for your time lookin at this post!

Let me know of what kinda of advice you have.